# Генератор уникальных значений php

Tags: php, yield

Есть массив с датами

```
$dates = [
    '2018-04-01', '2018-04-02', '2018-04-02',
    '2018-04-02', '2018-04-03', '2018-04-04',
    '2018-04-05', '2018-04-05', '2018-04-05'
];

//Генератор
function arr($arr){
    foreach($arr as $item){
        yield $item;
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы генератор запоминал только уникальные значения? Т.е. в итоге он должен будет содержать следующие значения: '2018-04-01', '2018-04-02', '2018-04-03', '2018-04-04', '2018-04-05'.

**P.S. Нужно обойтись без первоначальной обработки массива $dates, функциями типа array_unique().**

Comment: Без обработки - никак, только если не хранить то что в yield в отдельном массиве и не проверять если это было отдано раньше.

Comment: Как вы хотите получить уникальные значения, но при этом не заглядывать в массив? Почему вы не хотите обработки?

Comment: Про вариант из первого комментария я знал, хотелось реализовать с помощью генераторов) А какой тогда смысл в генераторе, если мы наполним массив уникальными значениями? Нам ведь его (массив) потом только вернуть останется. Идея была в том чтобы ускорить выполнение сценария + снизить потребление памяти.